# Bitmap is not showing in subsampling scale image view but shown in screenshot

Tags: android, layout, opengl-es, bitmap, custom-component

Given: Custom camera, zoomable image view and button in layout gone, 
device note 3
And: I capture image
Then: I visible layout and set bitmap to preview
as

```
if (bm != null){
previewContainer = visible
imgPreview.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bm));
}
```

It shows me the container but image is not drawn
I have try to redraw after this line

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().invalidate();
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().postInvalidateDelayed(20);
```

I does't shows loaded image.
And: Then I take screen shot. I can see image in screenshot but not in drawn layout. This sucks!. What is the problem actually?

Comment: Thanks #Android-Dev. Issue is due to hardware acceleration it has been resolved by myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: Qamar This worked for me, thanks. Could you post a link to where you got your answer so I can dig a bit deeper.

Comment: This issue raise in some devices due to hardware drivers. Image data is not passing to GPU. How Android Screenshot works then? I don't know more.